# How to get all images from gallery in API 29?

Tags: android, android-10.0

So I am loading all images from the gallery it is working fine but `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated. I am unable to find an example that using the latest method to perform this task without `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`

My Code right now

```
imageGallery = findViewById(R.id.image_grid);

        ArrayList<String> imagePathList = getGalleryImagesPath();

        final GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(AddPostActivity.this, imagePathList);

        imageGallery.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        imageGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Picasso.get().load(new File(gridAdapter.getItem(position))).resizeDimen(R.dimen.add_post_image, R.dimen.add_post_image).into(addPostImage);
                postButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

```
private ArrayList<String> getGalleryImagesPath() {

        ArrayList<String> imagePathList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        // MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA is deprecated
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};


        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                imagePathList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
            }

            cursor.close();
        }

        return imagePathList;
    }
```

```
    private static class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final ArrayList<String> imagePathList;
        private final Context context;

        GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imagePathList) {
            this.imagePathList = imagePathList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imagePathList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return imagePathList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            SquareImageView gridImage;

            if (convertView == null) {
                gridImage = new SquareImageView(context);

            } else {
                gridImage = (SquareImageView) convertView;
            }

            Picasso.get().load(new File(getItem(position))).resize(200, 200).into(gridImage);

            return gridImage;
        }
    }
```

**Update #1**

```
private ArrayList<Uri> getGalleryImagesPath() {

        ArrayList<Uri> imagePathList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                imagePathList.add(ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return imagePathList;
    }
```

Comment: Have `getGalleryImagesPath()` return an `ArrayList<Uri>`. Query the `MediaStore` to retrieve the `_ID` of the images. Use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to build a `Uri` based on your `Uri` from the query (`MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` in your current code) and the `_ID` for a given image. Use that to populate the returned `ArrayList` and use those `Uri` values with Picasso.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/RecyclerView/VideoList/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/RowController.java) for a Java example of using `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` and Picasso.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added an update can you have a look if it's fine?

Comment: Off the cuff, that looks OK. Picasso (or Glide) can then use the `Uri` to populate an `ImageView`. On Android 10+, you will need to hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to be able to access the images of other apps -- I cover that more in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/29/scoped-storage-stories-reading-mediastore.html).